# ionic application startup event

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a problem with my angularjs ionic application. During login we're loading various settings. If I kill the app and re-launch it these settings are not loaded.

I need to know if there's an event that is being invoked when the application launches so that I can reload my app settings.

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add the lines of code to load the settings either in **YourIndex.html's Controller** or you can put that code under `$ionicPlatform.ready`.

**Option 1:** Run it inside your **index.html**'s controller, because every time you open your app, this controller will be loaded.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic']);

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/')

    $stateProvider.state('index', {
        url: '/',
        controller: 'IndexCtrl',
    })
});

myApp.controller('IndexCtrl', function($scope) {
    //load your settings from localStorage or DB where you saved.
});
```

**Option 2:** Call every time Ionic calls [deviceReady](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready).

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic']);
myApp.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        //load your settings from localStorage or DB where you saved.
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In case some one looking for ionic 2 or 3, solution:

```
export class MyApp {

constructor() {
        platform.ready().then(() => {

            //DO WHATEVER

        });
    }
}
```