# On hard refresh, $rootScope disappears and cannot access current user

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using `$rootScope` to always access the current logged in user. When the user submits a new meal into the system the meal attributes are stored plus the user id who submitted them.

This works, but the moment I hard refresh my browser, the `$rootScope.user` object disappears.

How do I prevent that?

In `app.js` I have:

`$rootScope.user;`

Here's what happens when the user logs in:

```
Auth.$onAuth(function (user) {
                if (user === null) {
                    console.log("Not logged in yet");
                } else {
                    console.log("Logged in as", user.uid);
                }
                $rootScope.user = user;
        });
```

Then, when the user accesses the AddMeal page, within the `AddCtrl` we have:

```
var firebaseObj = new Firebase("https://myapp.firebaseio.com/courses/");
    var fb = $firebaseArray(firebaseObj);
console.log($rootScope.user)

$scope.newMeal = {
    name: "",
    price: "",
    ingredients: "",
    description: "",
    category: "",
    cuisine: "",
    userID:""
};

$scope.submitMeal = function () {
    if (angular.equals({}, $scope.newMeal)) {
        alert("Your form is empty");
        $rootScope.notify('Your form is empty')
    } else {
        console.log($scope.newMeal);
        var name = $scope.newMeal.name;
        var price =  $scope.newMeal.price;
        var ingredients= $scope.newMeal.ingredients;
        var description = $scope.newMeal.description;
        var category= $scope.newMeal.category;
        var cuisine= $scope.newMeal.cuisine;

        fb.$add({
            name: name,
            price: price,
            ingredients: ingredients,
            description: description,
            category: category,
            cuisine: cuisine,
            userID: $rootScope.user.uid
        }).then(function(ref) {
            $scope.newMeal = {};
            console.log(ref);
        }, function(error) {
            console.log("Error:", error);
        });

        $rootScope.notify('New meal has been added!')
    }
```

Here is my `run` function in `app.js`:

```
.run(function ($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $firebaseAuth, $firebase, $window, $ionicLoading) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
            // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
            // for form inputs)
            if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
                cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
                cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

            }
            if (window.StatusBar) {
                // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
                StatusBar.styleDefault();
            }

            $rootScope.show = function(text) {
                $rootScope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
                    content: text ? text : 'Loading..',
                    animation: 'fade-in',
                    showBackdrop: true,
                    maxWidth: 200,
                    showDelay: 0
                });
            };

            $rootScope.hide = function() {
                $ionicLoading.hide();
            };

            $rootScope.notify = function(text) {
                $rootScope.show(text);
                $window.setTimeout(function() {
                    $rootScope.hide();
                }, 1999);
            };

            $rootScope.user;

        });
    })
```

Comment: Can use sessionStorage to store a  user token and check if user is logged in on ever page load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS works as a SPA ([here](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) you can read a bit about it). The point is that when the page reloads, as any other SPA, it will lose all its data and the app will be "reeboted". This is why you are getting this problem.

There's an easy way to solve it:
When the app loads/reloads, it goes to the `app.config()` and rigth after that it goes to the `app.run()` (if any).
So my solution for you is to keep your user's info data on the localstorage (works like a cookie) and then ask for it from there when the app initialize.

```
angular.module('MyApp').run(function($rootScope){
    if(!angular.isDefined($rootScope.userInfo) && localstorage.userInfo){
        // UserInfo exists in localstorate but not on $rootScope. This means the page was reloaded or the user is returning.
        $rootScope.userInfo = localstorage.userInfo;
    }else if(!angular.isDefined($rootScope.userInfo) && !localstorage.userInfo){
        // User is not logged at all. Send him back to login page
    }else if(angular.isDefined($rootScope.userInfo)){
        // User is logged in. You can run some extra validations in here.
    }
});
```

I'm assuming you keep your users info on a variable `$rootScope.userInfo`

That been said, I strongly recommend you try a Service to keep your data rather than on the $rootScope. [Here's](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) a guide on how you can achieve that.

I hope this solves your issue.

**UPDATE

If you're working with Ionic you can try something like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic']);
    myApp.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        //load your settings from localStorage or DB where you saved.
    });
});
```

Took it from this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29469291/ionic-application-startup-event).

Comment: Hi Gerardo, I will give this a go! Just FYI, I was initially trying to use a service to get the Users - see this question I posted - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36225588/cant-get-firebase-reference-to-id-to-define-current-user. However I found that for some reason the items I wanted from the service were appearing in a console.log in my controller outside a `$waitForAuth` but not within a `$waitForAuth` function.

Comment: Keeping the globals on a service is consider to be a good practice, but if for some reason you find trouble, you are always good to go with what best suits you. Just don't be to harsh with the `$rootScope`, it can become hard for your app to be reading from it.

Comment: Hi @Gerardo, I was trying to understand how I could adapt my code to fit yours and where to refactor my code for the `run` function as I don't want to upset things like `$ionicPlatform.ready()`. Would you mind adjusting your answer for this?

Comment: I updated my answer. Hopefully I can asnwer your question with that last update.