# How to obtain the user profile from a Users service within AngularFire, Ionic and Firebase

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I have been experimenting with various ways to obtain the current user profile from a database, just like I used to use `session_start()` in PHP to get all the variables I need.

Here is my data structure:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "7fb5c5fd-34fe-47da-b5e9-f8faa23aea1c" : {
      "email" : "bl@bt.com",
      "firstname" : "bla",
      "lastname" : "bear",
      "uid" : "7fb5c5fd-34fe-47da-b5e9-f8faa23aea1c"
    },
    "d4d3e89f-ad51-4206-b347-e8273e2cbd78" : {
      "email" : "hey@t.com",
      "firstname" : "dfads",
      "lastname" : "dfsda",
      "uid" : "d4d3e89f-ad51-4206-b347-e8273e2cbd78"
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my `Auth` factory which does things like log out, store the current user profile as an object and so on.

```
app.factory('Auth', ['rootRef', '$firebaseObject','$firebaseAuth', function (rootRef, $firebaseObject,$firebaseAuth) {

    var auth = $firebaseAuth(rootRef);
    var user = new $firebaseObject;

    auth.$onAuth(function (authData) {
        if (authData) {
            angular.copy(authData, user);
            // Set the profile
            user = $firebaseObject(rootRef.child('users').child(authData.uid));
            user.$loaded().then(function (user) {
                $window.localStorage['uid'] = user.uid.toString();
                $window.localStorage['profile'] = user;
                console.log('Window storage uid is' + $window.localStorage['uid']);
            });
        } else {
            if (user!=null) {
                user.$destroy();
            }
        }
    });

    return {
        user: user,
        login: function (user) {
            return auth.$authWithPassword({
                email: user.email,
                password: user.password
            })
        },
        logout: function(auth) {
            return auth.$unauth;
        },
        signedIn: function (user) {
            return !!user.provider;
        }
    }


}]);
```

What I want to do is load the profile data of the user when they log in to a profile page, so we see the first name, last name and other things we stored when they first signed in and we stored these variables in the `users` array.

But I am getting:

```
ionic.bundle.js:25642 TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined
```

I previously tried to solve this problem by using `$rootScope.user` and by using my `LoginCtrl` and saying:

```
Auth.$onAuth(function (AuthData) {
                if (AuthData === null) {
                    console.log("Not logged in yet");
                } else {
                    var uid = Auth.$getAuth().uid;
                    var user = new Firebase(FirebaseUrl).child(users).child(uid).val();
                    user.$loaded().then(function (profile) {
                                    $rootScope.user= profile;
                                })
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
```

And then

```
$scope.user = $rootScope.user;
```

This worked, but when I hard refreshed the browser the `$rootScope` object became null.

Any ideas how I can best achieve what I am trying to do, and most importantly where I should put each part of code given what my data structure?

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36238392/on-hard-refresh-rootscope-disappears-and-cannot-access-current-user)? The text is different, but the problem reads the same to me (a hard refresh logs the user out).

Comment: Here I am trying to use `$window.localStorage`, and also my data structure is completely different. But my objective is the same - please see comment on the other question on your answer. Thank you!

Comment: There are too many moving parts here and the use of `localStorage` looks suspicious. Can you isolate and reproduce the problem in a site like jsbin/jsfiddle?